# Windows 10 fails to authorize to Ubuntu Samba share

Tags: permissions, samba, windows-10

I was running a server with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I had a Samba share setup with several "usershares". I did not do the original setup for this and am not completely sure how it worked. However, I was able to connect from my Windows 10 machine to the share and access the various files.

There were some issues, relating to things like guest permissions and so forth. However, I was required to update the server to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. When I tried to re-implement the Samba share, I am unable to connect and always get either password error or no error but no connection. I am able to connect and access the share from my alternate Windows 7 machine.

By increasing the logging level, the only difference I can see between these two attempts is that the Win7 log shows the following:

```
[2023/10/24 18:34:38.826387,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:509(ntlmssp_server_preauth) Got user=[Brian] domain=[HW-ARCHIVE] workstation=[HW-ARCHIVE] len1=24 len2=24
```

Whereas the Win10 log shows:

```
[2023/10/24 18:38:16.216284,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:509(ntlmssp_server_preauth) Got user=[brian] domain=[.] workstation=[BRIAN-2018] len1=24 len2=24
```

It appears the only difference is the `domain=[]` field.

I have no idea how this field is set in Windows or how to bypass it or any other way around the issue. I have been struggling with this issue for at least a day and any other insights would be appreciated.

Comment: So I "resolved" this issue by adding a new share open to "nobody" and then created my shared workspace within that new share. I removed the "usershare" and pretty much gave up on that whole concept. Form the Windows perspective, it now works essentially as well as it did before. I still don't really know how to fix it properly, though.